# Is it true that n is always greater than or equal to harmonic_number(n)?

Tags: inequality, harmonic-numbers

My question is:

Prove or disprove: For any number $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n > 0$, 
$$n \ge H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$h(n) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{i}$$ and $$n = \sum_{i=1}^n 1.$$ Now hopefully you can see how to compare these two quantities to confirm your suspicion.

Comment: Dang! It's been a while since I have done math, and I just threw it up there. Thank you!